# Two objects of equal and opposite velocities collide elastically. If the two objects have different masses, which one has a bigger final speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, conservation-laws, collision

**Question: Two objects, one less massive than the other, collide elastically and bounce back after the collision. If the
two originally had velocities that were equal in size but opposite in direction, then which one will be
moving faster after the collision?**

1. The less massive one.
2. The more massive one.
3. The speeds will be the same after the collision.
4. There is no way to be sure without the actual masses.

*ANSWER: 1*

---

Assume that $v_{1f} = -v_{1i}$ and $v_{2f} = -v_{2i}$. Given that $v_{1i} = -v_{2i}, m_1 > m_2 \Rightarrow \Sigma{p_i} = m_{1}v_{i} - m_{2}v_{i} \neq \Sigma{p_f} = -m_{1}v_{i} + m_{2}v_{i}$.

In other words, we can exclude answer #3 because if the objects were to bounce back at the same initial speed (only reversing direction), conservation of momentum would be violated.

But for the life of me I can't rigorously prove why the answer can't be #2. Given that the collision is elastic, I tried using:

$(1) \frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1i}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_{2i}^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1f}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_{2f}^2$

$(2) v_{1i} - v_{2i} = v_{2f} - v_{2i}$

to arrive at a proof, but to no avail. I intuitively know that the magnitude of the heavier object's velocity would be less than that of the lighter object, but if someone could explain the math behind it I would greatly appreciate it.

*P.S.* All textbooks mention the elastic collision between two equal masses case (momenta are exchanged), but I couldn't find anything during my search that talked equal and opposite velocities but different masses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually is not too hard.

The first thing to note, the initial momentum of the 2 mass system is along the direction of the heavier mass.

Let's say both have an initial velocity $v_0$ opposite direction to each other, and the direction of M's initial velocity as positive (M>m). And, after collision lets say $m$ and $M$ have velocity $v_1$, $v_2$ respectively in **opposite direction**. So $v_1$ is in the direction of the velocity of M's velocity before the collision. So we can write momentum conservation, we know initial momentum in direction M's velocity before collision is positive so we have:

$$mv_1-Mv_2>0 \implies v_1>\frac{M}{m}v_2 >v_2 \implies v_1>v_2$$

Hence the smaller ball has more speed after collison.